# Set selected index in a Dropdownlist in usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I'm fairly new to usercontrols.  So far, I've found them quite useful for handling large amounts of repeating user input fields.  However, I'm having a problem with prepopulating a dropdownlist in the control.  I add a ddl to my ascx page then I bind the ddl and expose it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Travel_CarSize> tc = Travel_CarSizes.GetCarSizes();
        ddlCarSize.DataSource = tc;
        ddlCarSize.DataTextField = "CarSize";
        ddlCarSize.DataValueField = "CarSizeID";
        ddlCarSize.DataBind();
    }
}

public string CarSize
{
    get { return ddlCarSize.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
    set { ddlCarSize.SelectedIndex = ddlCarSize.Items.IndexOf(ddlCarSize.Items.FindByValue(value)); }
}
```

However, when I programatically try to set a selection for the ddl in the control I always end up setting it THEN binding it.  In my aspx.cs file I set:

```
CarControl1.CarSize = "3";
```

The program is designed to display an empty usercontrol (with a databound ddl) and a gridview.  The user selects a gridview entry and that usercontrol gets filled with the data.  So the ddl gets bound from the start then the events happen that lead to the "pre-selected" ddl.

When this didn't give me the result I was looking for I put a breakpoint on the if(!IsPostBack), the ddlCarSize.DataBind(); and the set{}.  I run the program, it binds my ddl and I make a selection in the gridview.  When I click the select I found that it hits the if(!IsPostBack) in the usercontrol and says "Oh, this is a postback, don't go in the if." then it hits the set{} but the ddl is empty now.  Then it hits the if(!IsPostBack) again and for some reason now says it's not a postback and rebinds the ddl.

I figure this is a pretty common problem but I've yet to find a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Bind()
    }
}

public Bind()
{
    if (ddlCarSize.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        List<Travel_CarSize> tc = Travel_CarSizes.GetCarSizes();
        ddlCarSize.DataSource = tc;
        ddlCarSize.DataTextField = "CarSize";
        ddlCarSize.DataValueField = "CarSizeID";
        ddlCarSize.DataBind();
    }
}

public string CarSize
{
    get { return ddlCarSize.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
    set 
    {
        Bind();
        ddlCarSize.SelectedIndex = ddlCarSize.Items.IndexOf(ddlCarSize.Items.FindByValue(value)); }
}
```

Comment: Hunter, you are my new personal hero.  It's such a simple solution and it never crossed my mind.  Thank you.