# How to implement Generics in business object class definition with DAL to create a proper user control dropdown

Tags: asp.net, generics, user-controls, drop-down-menu

I am woefully new to generics, being tied to the support of a corporate intranet web application whose upgrade process is bound to red tape and slowwwly-changing standards. Consequently, today (thankfully!) I finally find myself scrambling during our upgrade to .Net 3.5 and transitioning all the code I can to a properly tiered model.

I have been reading all morning about generics trying to digest how to transition dropdown user controls into a proper business object that gets its data from a class in the data access layer.

There is a perfectly succinct question here that details exactly what I am interested in exploring: [Set selected index in a Dropdownlist in usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156037/set-selected-index-in-a-dropdownlist-in-usercontrol).

What I would love to see, however, is what `Travel_CarSizes.GetCarSizes()` actually looks like inside and how the class `Travel_CarSizes` is defined. (I am having a hard time with `<T>` and knowing where it should occur.)

For my own specific circumstance at the moment I need a dropdown user control to contain location directionals (N, S, W, C/O, NW, SE, etc) that are stored in a SQL table in the DB and whose selected index needs to be able to be set by whichever page it happens to be in, when form data exists.

I have begun to implement the model in the example from the link above but right now **without using Generics** because I can't figure it out:

The dropdown user control:

```
public partial class DropDownStreetPrefix : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string StreetPrefixValue
    {
        get { return ddlStreetPrefix.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            Bind();
            ddlStreetPrefix.SelectedIndex = ddlStreetPrefix.Items.IndexOf(ddlStreetPrefix.Items.FindByValue(value));
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Bind();             
        }

    }

    private void Bind()
    {
        if (ddlStreetPrefix.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            SqlDataReader rdr = StreetDirectionals.GetDirectionals();
            ddlStreetPrefix.DataSource = rdr;
            ddlStreetPrefix.DataBind();

            ddlStreetPrefix.DataValueField = "StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";
            ddlStreetPrefix.DataTextField = "StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";

            ListItem li = new ListItem("", "");
            ddlStreetPrefix.Items.Insert(0, li);
            ddlStreetPrefix.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `StreetDirectionals` class:

```
public class StreetDirectionals
{
    private StreetDirectionals () { }

    public static SqlDataReader GetDirectionals ()
    {
        string sqlText = "SELECT StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr FROM common..tblStreetSuffixPrefix " +
            "ORDER BY StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";

        SqlDataReader rdr = SqlClient.ExecuteFetchReturnDataReader( theConnectionString, CommandType.Text, sqlText);

        return rdr;
    }

}
```

I will separate out the database interaction inside the `StreetDirectionals` class as soon as I can figure out how to change its code if I were to transform the Bind() method from my dropdown user control into this:

```
private void Bind()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        **List<StreetDirectionals> sd = StreetDirectionals.GetDirectionals();**
        ddlStreetPrefix.DataSource = sd;
        ddlStreetPrefix.DataTextField = "StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";
        ddlStreetPrefix.DataValueField = "StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";
        ddlStreetPrefix.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be sooo much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not really clear in what way you want assistance - what part of the issue do you expect Generics to help you with? Is it that you want StreetDirectionals.GetDirectionals to return a StreetDirectional class rather than a SqlDataReader?

Comment: I believe what I want, which is what the example I cited seemed to portray, is the return of a generic list by `StreetDirectionals.GetDirectionals()` rather than a `SqlDataReader.` I would like to keep database-specific functionality restricted to the data layer. I thought (but perhaps I'm wrong?) that the example was allowing the other developer to do just that. It's quite possible I'm not asking the question correctly though, given how new I am to generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class StreetDirectional
{
    public string StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<StreetDirectional> GetDirectionals ()
    {
        string sqlText = "SELECT StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr FROM common..tblStreetSuffixPrefix " 
            + "ORDER BY StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr";

        SqlDataReader rdr = SqlClient.ExecuteFetchReturnDataReader( theConnectionString, CommandType.Text, sqlText);

        var list = new List<StreetDirectional>();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var item = new StreetDirectional() { StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr = (string)rdr["StreetSuffixPrefixAbbr"] };
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

then you can do this

```
ddlStreetPrefix.DataSource = StreetDirectional.GetDirectionals();
```

Comment: You are fantastic, thank you thank you! I am beginning to understand now that I see that implementation.